# Release Management timeout after two hours during a "deploy using PS" action

Tags: release-management, ms-release-management

At my work, we use Release Management (Visual Studio 2013) to deploy various websites, webservices, winservices and databases through the use of "Deploy Using PS/DSC" PowerShell scripts. Since we don't have direct access to our database servers, we have a separate template that uses PowerShell scripts to run one-time .sql scripts to fill new database tables for example. These scripts makes use of sqlcmd.exe to run the queries.

This has been working fine so far, but right now there is a particular query that takes a few hours to run. After running for just over 2 hours, the action returns as Failed, with the following message in the Log:
*Action timed out, setting the status as failed*

I have been trying to find a place in the web.config where there is a timeout value of 2 hours, but no such luck sadly. Googling this message has left me with no useful results. I would love some advice on what the culprit might be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to increase the timeout of a vNext action (Deploy using PS/DSC) in your case, open the `ReleaseManagementMonitor.exe.config` file available at

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\ReleaseManagement\bin
```

Look for an app setting - `<add key="ActivityTimeoutInMinutes" value="120"/>`

This 120 minutes is the timeout that applies to your action. Increase this value and you are good to go.

**PS** - make sure you don't have any running releases and then restart the monitor service for the changes to take effect.

Comment: Thanks for the swift answer! Sadly I forgot to restart the Release Management Monitor after changing the .config (too used to editing web.configs I suppose), so it will be another two hours before I can *hopefully* mark this one as the answer.

Comment: Ouch, i've added that little detail to the answer as well.